# Session is expired even though websocket connection is live

Tags: java, session, tomcat, websocket, java-ee-7

My requirement is as below:

1. Login with the application.
2. Open websocket connection on successfully login
3. exchange data bidirectionally thorough websocket but there's no direct communication via HTTP

I have configured session-timeout > 15mins in web.xml. Even though, websocket connection is live, but session is terminated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in java websocket specification for Websocket message handshake is not going to update accesstime. Due to that if we specify expiration policy in any server which complies to Java Specification will not update accesstime on websocket message exchange. So, it is advisable to set higher expiration value or infinite session expiration time.

References:
Tomcat Ticket: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54738
Java Specification Ticket: https://java.net/jira/browse/WEBSOCKET_SPEC-175

Answer (score 1):

You will have to find a way of pushing the session´s sliding expiration in java. Since no new HTTP requests are being done, the session will expire if you do not do anything about it.

Try to call [setMaxInactiveInterval](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setMaxInactiveInterval(int)) with a value every time you receive a message through the websocket, it may reset the tiemr.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't have an instance of HttpSession during websocket communication. So how i can reset timer?